# Superset chart email schedules and celery beat schedule. Why report is sent with celery beat schedule instead of chart email schedules?

Tags: apache-superset

My configured email report is named "Raw player games" with crontab */20 * * * * (At every 20th minute I will expect a report in my email box). Look in the screenshot [raw player games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIT2T.png).

Another crontab is configured in main superset config - superset_config.py

```
# superset_config.py

    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'email_reports.schedule_hourly': {
            'task': 'email_reports.schedule_hourly',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=1, hour='*'), # At minute 1, every hour
        },
    }
```

I receive [emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEgh1.png), but only one per hour. I don't see any errors in logs, all jobs in celery flower are in success state.

```
apache-superset==0.37.2
celery==4.4.7
```

**Why?**
Why superset send me reports only once in a hour? How to reconfigure superset to correctly handle my crontabs, what I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your beat schedule is configured to run hourly. So on every minute one of each hour, beat is going to enqueue a new job that will verify if it's time to send a new report. It will not matter to have a thinner resolution configured on superset itself.

Yet by default email reports functionality has an hourly resolution:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset/tasks/schedules.py#L823

This default can be changed by configuring:
`EMAIL_REPORTS_CRON_RESOLUTION`